# type name not found in the vice chess engine

Tags: error-handling, typename

In Polykey.h it has extern const U64 Random64Poly[781];
There are alot of U64 in the program, so redefining U64 refines
all the U64 in the program. Lots of errors in compiling under cxxdroid in android.
Just cannot get this fixed. Vice is programmed in the c language.

I tried typedef and making astruct,neither worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please explain what it is you're trying to compile and include your code.   It isn't clear why you need to redefine U64.

Comment: U64 is the type name that's not recognized

Comment: What is your code like?